# Non-Primitive Values from a Registered Content Provider are not showing a value

Tags: arrays, json, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm using the `/v2/registrations` endpoint to register a content provider with the `legacyForwarding` flag being set. Therefore my Content Provider is offering the `v1/queryContext` endpoint

When I am returning a **simple value** (Integer, String etc.) such as a `temperature` the data is added to the context correctly:

```
{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "temperature",
                        "type": "Number",
                        "value": 27
                    }
                ],
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "type": "Store"
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However when trying to return an **array** of strings as shown from a Context Provider.

```
{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "tweets",
                        "type": "Array",
                        "value": [
                            "String 1",
                            "String 2"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:002",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "type": "Store"
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see the request being sent in the log and I can retrieve the following entity:

```
{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:002",
    "type": "Store",
    "address": {
        "type": "PostalAddress",
        "value": "",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "geo:json",
        "value": "",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Checkpoint Markt",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "tweets": {
        "type": "Array",
        "value": "",
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

As you can see the `"tweets"` value is blank, but the attribute  exists and the type has been successfully received.

My question is how should I return an `Array` or an `Object` as a value from a Content Provider so that Orion is able to display the data received correctly?

Comment: Looks Like this might be a bug - I have created issue on [github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3162)

Comment: Let's keep this question opened until the bug gets fixed. When fixed, an answer should be added, including the Orion version in which the fix is available.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation from the [Orion Team](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3162) shows that this was indeed a bug and an issue was raised against **Orion 2.0.0**. With the latest release, the bug has now been fixed.

The solution is to upgrade to a later version of Orion - currently **2.1.0** (at the time of writing)